# Using Socket.io and Matlab

Tags: matlab, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I've set a [socket.io](http://socket.io/) server (nodejs) on localhost

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    setInterval(function(){
        socket.emit("updatedPrice", 100.3);
    },2000);
});
```

I've tested this on my browser and it works correctly.

But, if I cannot read data on Matlab

```
>> tcpipClient = tcpip('localhost',8000,'NetworkRole','Client')

   TCPIP Object : TCPIP-localhost

   Communication Settings 
      RemotePort:         8000
      RemoteHost:         localhost
      Terminator:         'LF'
      NetworkRole:        client

   Communication State 
      Status:             closed
      RecordStatus:       off

   Read/Write State  
      TransferStatus:     idle
      BytesAvailable:     0
      ValuesReceived:     0
      ValuesSent:         0


>> set(tcpipClient,'InputBufferSize',7688);
>> set(tcpipClient,'Timeout',30);
>> fopen(tcpipClient);
>> rawData = fread(tcpipClient,961,'double');
Warning: Unsuccessful read:  The specified amount of data was not returned
within the Timeout period.
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be resurecting an old question, but it's something I didn't understand at first so hopefully it will be helpful to someone else out there.

I'm assuming you used the client side socket.io library when you say "I've tested this on my browser and it works correctly". This is how socket.io is meant to function, and as far as I know, the only way it will function. This is because socket.io is a relatively high-level library that is giving a lot of functionality for the web with broadcasting to multiple websockets, etc. Notably, socket.io doesn't even use websockets by default, it "upgrades" to them based on availability, while being able to fallback on older solutions like long polling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO). Websockets is a protocol that in itself is most likely implemented over the tcp/ip protocol, but there's no way that the tcp/ip function in matlab is going to communicate with socket.io unless you specifically implement socket.io's use of websockets. Even if you could, it would be messy and far more work than it's worth.

My suggestion for communication between matlab and node would be to stick with either the tcp/ip protocol, or the websockets protocol based on your intended use. Matlab has websockets compatibilty through external code (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50040-jebej-matlabwebsocket), and node's npm will provide you with modules to communicate over either tcp/ip or websockets.